# Securing SpringBoot REST endpoints in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: rest, google-app-engine, spring-boot, spring-security

I created a SpringBoot application with a couple of REST endpoints and deployed it to Google App Engine Standard. Everything works fine and I am able to hit the endpoints. 
Now I want to secure these endpoints and allow only users authorized as admin to be able to call one of the endpoints. I tried to add a web.xml file to my project with the following configuration:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>api</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>status</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/status</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>ping</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/ping</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
```

I can deploy this to GAE, but I cannot call the endpoints anymore. All I get now is a bunch of 404 not found, on the same URL as before. Is there any other way to secure SpringBoot endpoints in Google App Engine Standard?

Forgot to mention that the security configuration works when I run the app locally, but start getting 404s as soon as I deploy to GAE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Google Cloud support, it is not possible to secure a Spring application with Google APP engine configuration files. It needs to be done like any other Spring application, but if you go with OAUTH for example you need to use Google libraries for token authentication.